# move rotated ol.style.text relative to a given point in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, rotation, openlayers-3

I will try to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.
I have a point feature to which I set an array of 2 styles: 1 style represents a rotated image at the given point, the second one should be a rotated text at a fixed distance of the given point.

To clarify things I've created an image. I want to achieve the situation on the right. (the x,y,z lines and labels are for explanation purposes). I want to move the text over a fixed distance **z**. The rotation angle is also variable.

[image: point with rotated text]

So what I did was give a `rotation` to the [ol.style.text](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html) object and then give the text an offset for Y but then the text gets pulled straight below the point.

What I am looking for is a method to offset the text for a given distance, taking the rotation in account, without having to manually set the `ofssetX` and `offsetY`.

One solution here is indeed to use geometry.. calculate x and y offset based on the angles and the given z , using the sin formulas and the Pythagorean theorem, but I would like to avoid those calculations and find a more simple resolution.

I am using the latest version of openlayers3, currently v3.16.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you put your starting code in a fiddle?